# How can I make argparse apply type conversion to default value of positional arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

`argparse` applies type conversion to arguments of options, and to the default values of these if the default values are strings. However, it seems it doesn't do so for positional arguments:

```
import argparse as ap

p = ap.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('file', nargs='*',
                metavar='FILE',
                default='-',
                type=ap.FileType(),
                help='Input files. - is stdin. Default: %(default)s')

print(p.parse_args([]))
# Namespace(file='-')
print(p.parse_args(['-']))
# Namespace(file=[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>])
```

([Ideone](http://ideone.com/mXud9K))

If I change `file` to `--file` so that these are option arguments, the `default` value is converted as expected.

Do I have any options better than explicitly passing `argparse.FileType()('-')` as the `default`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values put into `sys.argv` are always `str` objects, because the underlying operating system construct is an array is C character pointers. You need `type` to convert them to some other Python type.

The value of `default`, however, is under no such restriction. You can use a value of any type you like for that keyword argument.

```
p.add_argument('file',
                nargs='*',
                metavar='FILE',
                default=[sys.stdin],
                type=ap.FileType(),
                help='Input files. - is stdin. Default: standard input')
```

I modified the help; getting the value of `repr(sys.stdin)` isn't particular useful, and the user should not be confused by describing the default value rather than specifying an exact Python object.

Comment: I understand the first part well enough, but I don't see how that has anything to do with this. As for the second, what if the default file I use is `'/some/file'` instead of `'-'`?

Comment: `default=ap.FileType('/some/file')`. The default value simply is not subject to processing by the defined type.

Comment: (I'm checking the source code, though, to make sure I'm not missing something. It's a complex process.)

Comment: It is, if the default value is for an *option*: http://ideone.com/2WX6hn. I'm asking how to achieve the same behaviour to positional parameters (this much is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default): "If the default value is a string, the parser parses the value as if it were a command-line argument. In particular, the parser applies any type conversion argument, if provided, ...")

Comment: Defaults for * and ? positionals are handled in a special way.  That kind of positional is always `seen` because a empty list meets its nargs requirement. The relevant code is in a method called IRC `_get_values`. Handling defaults is a complex business.

Comment: One of the conditions for applying the type conversion to values for *required* arguments is that the name already exist in the namespace; I *think* this is to accommodate multiple arguments that share the same destination.

Comment: @hpaulj indeed the code is explicit about this: default values for options are converted if they are strings, but default values for positional parameters are used as is. See the difference between lines 2244 and 2252 in that function: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/argparse.py#l2252 (thanks for that)

Comment: It's interesting that `?' passes the string default through `type` (_get_value), but `*` does not.  I have a feeling that I have explored this difference in another SO question or bug/issue.

Comment: @hpaulj so this is intentional and there's not hope of getting the same behaviour for positionals as for options?

Comment: I couldn't find any other bug/issue related to this issue; `argparse` patching proceeds at a snail's pace, to avoid backward compatibility issues.  Stick with the `[sys.stdin]` approach.  It's simpler - and gives you more control.  `type` conversion of a default is (nearly) always a convenience, not a necessity.